# What does the number (9) mean in the header?

Tags: discussion, review

The number beside review is not going away, but there are no available reviews. I just got 2000 rep points. I am not going to correct spelling or edit unless it is to help the OP. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Correcting spelling and grammar is important because when people search for help they're not going to know what wrong spelling to use.

Comment: @Leopoldo Sparks I can see that in the header or question, but in the body? Some of the corrections just feel like a teacher correcting to exact standards. I either use voice to type or use my arthritic fingers. Either way, I make mistakes and truthfully, unless it was a very important word, I would not dare to edit. If I screw up my own post, I only hurt myself. I also understand completely that you and others get to make these decisions for yourselves. My opinion is not the right one -- just my own. Nothing special about it.

Comment: @WillowRex Searches look through the body as well.

Comment: they do? I tried and tried and never found the phrase I used. I had copied and pasted that phrase from an existing post. I will try again. Thanks.

Comment: @called2voyage I just tried it again and it completely worked. Thanks. I have no idea what I did wrong before, or if was a momentary problem, but that does change things.

Answer (score 2):

You can only contribute a fraction of what's needed to get the item off the review queue. Many review 'tasks' take more than one vote to be cleared, for example, it takes five votes from five different users to close (or reopen) a question. The red review notice numeral will not change on your vote unless you are casting the fifth vote.

So... it takes a village to clear the queues.

The fact that your queues are empty means you've done all you can do already on the posts in the queues. Good job!

Comment: thanks, I am a slow learner when it comes to understanding this site. I will get there though.